Is $X \mapsto \operatorname{tr}( DXAX^TD^T - DXCD - DC^TX^TD)$ a convex function?
I know that $ g \left( X \right) = \operatorname{tr}( XAX^T - XC - C^TX^T )$ is a convex function.
Is $ h \left( X \right) = \operatorname{tr}( DXAX^TD^T - DXCD - DC^TX^TD )$ still a convex function？
here $X$ is an $n$ by $m$ variable matrix, $C$ is an $m$ by $n$ constant matrix, $A$ is an $m$ by $m$ symmetric, positive definite constant matrix. $D$ is a diagonal constant matrix.
My use case is that I can setup a convex optimization problem minimize trace of $XAX^T - XC - C^TX^T$ but now I want to add a weight to it by multiplying the diagnal matrix on both sides....

$\mathrm{tr}(UU^T)=\sum U_{ij}^2$, so it is convex, here $U=DX\mathrm{chol}(A)$ (similar in the original case). It also gives you a conic model.

Note that $f(X)=\operatorname{tr}(DXAX^TD)$ is mid-point convex because
\begin{align}
&\frac{f(X)+f(Y)}{2}-f\left(\frac{X+Y}{2}\right)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}\left(\dfrac{DXAX^TD+DYAY^TD}{2}
-D\left(\frac{X+Y}{2}\right)A\left(\frac{X+Y}{2}\right)^TD\right)\\
&=\frac14\operatorname{tr}\left(D(X-Y)A(X-Y)^TD\right)\ge0.
\end{align}
Since it is also continuous in $X$, it is convex. It follows that $X\mapsto\operatorname{tr}(DXAX^TD - DXCD - DC^TX^TD)$ is also convex because it is the sum of $f$ and a linear function in $X$.


Let $f(X)=\operatorname{tr}(DXAX^\top D)$.
Then $\frac{d f}{d X} = 2 D^\top D X A $.
This yields $H = \frac{d^2 f}{d X^2} = A \otimes (D^\top D) $.

By Schur product theorem $H$ is PSD hence the function is convex as other terms are linear within a linear operator.
